# looping error causing and endless scroll in blackjack game

Tags: python, blackjack

I'm currently working on a blackjack game for my class and I think I've just about wrapped it up but for some reason I get stuck in an endless loop that keeps restarting the game. Can you help me find it?

```
import random as r

class Card:

    def __init__(self, rank, suit, value):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + ' of ' + self.suit

class Deck:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.shuffle()
        
    def shuffle(self):
        suits = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
        ranks = ['Ace', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']

        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                value = ranks.index(rank) + 1
                if value > 10: value = 10
                if value == 1: value = 11
                card = Card(rank, suit, value)
                self.cards.append(card)

    def deal(self):
        if len(self.cards) < 1: self.shuffle()
        index = r.randint(0, len(self.cards) - 1)
        return self.cards.pop(index)
                
class Hand:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def deal(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)
        return self.value()

    def value(self):
        score = 0
        aces = 0
        for card in self.cards:
            score += card.value
            if card.value == 11: aces += 1

        while score > 21 and aces > 1:
            score -= 10
            aces -= 1
        return score

class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = Deck()
        self.player = Hand()
        self.dealer = Hand()
        self.wins = 0
        self.losses = 0
        self.exit = False
        while not self.exit:
            self.play()

    def play(self):

        self.deal()

        if self.playerphase():

            if self.dealerphase():

                if self.player.value() > self.dealer.value():
                    self.outcome('player')
                elif self.player.value() < self.dealer.value():
                    self.outcome('dealer')
                else: self.outcome('pushback')

            else: self.outcome('player', bust = True)

        else: self.outcome('dealer', bust = True)    

    def deal(self):
        self.player = Hand()
        self.dealer = Hand()
        for x in range(2):
            self.player.deal(self.deck.deal())
            self.dealer.deal(self.deck.deal())

    def playerphase(self):
        stand = False
        options = ['hit', 'stand']
        prompts = ["Enter 'hit or 'stand':"]
        while not stand:
            call = self.display(options, prompts)
            if call == 'hit':
                self.player.deal(self.deck.deal())
                if self.player.value() > 21:
                    stand = True
            else: stand = True
        if self.player.value() > 21: return False
        else: return True

    def dealerphase(self):
        while self.dealer.value() < 17:
            self.dealer.deal(self.deal.deal())
        if self.dealer.value() > 21: return False
        else: return True      

    def display(self, options, prompts, show=False):
        user = ''
        while user not in options:
            
            for x in range(30): print()
            print('Wins: ' + str(self.wins))
            print('Losses: ' + str(self.losses))
            print('\nDealer: ')
            if show: print(self.dealer.cards[0])
            else: print('Face-Down Card')
            for x in range (1, len(self.dealer.cards)):
                print(self.dealer.cards[x])
            print('\nPlayer:')
            for card in self.player.cards:
                print(card)

                
            for prompt in prompts: print(prompt)

            user = ''
        

        return user

    def outcome(winner, bust = False):

        prompts = []
        options = ['play', 'exit']

        if winner == 'player':
            prompts.append('player wins!')
            if bust: prompts.append('dealer busts')
            self.wins += 1
        elif winner == 'dealer':
            prompts.append('Dealer wins :(')
            if bust: prompts.append('player busts')
            self.losses += 1
        else: prompts.append('Pushback!')

        call = self.display(options, prompts, show = True)
        if call == 'exit': self.exit = True
            
game = Game()
```

Comment: Code blocks are denoted by backticks (`), not apostrophes. [Formatting help](/help/formatting)

Comment: Now's a good time to learn [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [to use a debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)  
Step through your code and observe what each line of code does. 
Identify where your program differs from your expectations by comparing these intermediate results with expected results. 
Work backwards from there to narrow down the cause of the problem. 
Then ask a _specific_ question if you are still confused by your code's behavior. It's not okay to dump your code and expect other people to debug it for you.

Comment: Please also take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and provide a [mre] that reproduces your problem with the minimum amount of code, after you have done some debugging yourself to figure out what causes the problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow!